# Выборка из базы данных по совпадению 2-х значений одного столбца

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, выборка

В общем запрос такой

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `option_value_id`='49' AND `option_value_id`='50' ORDER BY `product_id` ASC
```

Пытаюсь выбрать id записи значение которых равны `option_value_id`='50' и `option_value_id`='49' Нужно вывести id у которых есть именно 2 таких совпадения, если совпадает только 1 запись то id не должен попасть в выборку.

В базе записи имеют такой формат 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каким по вашему образом `optional_value_id` у **одной** строки может иметь сразу два знанчения? А если вам надо выбрать две строки, у которых `optional_value_id` равен **или** одному значению или другому, то `AND` надо заменить на `OR`.

Comment: смысл в том что бы выбрать id у которых есть и значение 49 и значение 50, но походу чисто через sql такую выборку нельзя реализовать, наверное нужно с помощью php делать условие и проверку на совпадение.

Comment: @igorauscas, в sql можно делать все)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то примерно так:

```
SELECT `product_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`option_value_id`)) AS `variants` 
FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `option_value_id`='49' OR `option_value_id`='50' 
GROUP BY `product_id` HAVING `variants`='2'
```

Comment: А как сделать обратное действие не подскажете? То есть выбрать товары у которых только одно совпадение например по полю `option_value_id`='49'
Если сделать такой запрос
     SELECT `product_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`option_value_id`)) AS `variants` 
FROM `oc_product_option_value` WHERE `option_value_id`='49' OR `option_value_id`='50' 
GROUP BY `product_id` HAVING `variants`='1'
то выведет все записи у которых совпадение по одному из столбцов

Comment: Немного не понял задачу. Что именно нужно получить и чем это должно отличаться от варианта с `HAVING variants='1`?

Comment: Вариант HAVING variants='1' выбирает все позиции у которых есть совпадение либо option_value_id='49' либо option_value_id='50'
А мне нужно что бы запрос проверил если у позиции нету совпадений по обоим вариантам то выводим позиции только у которых есть совпадение по option_value_id='49'

Comment: А чем это будет отличаться от запроса только тех позиций, у которых есть совпадение по option_value_id='49'? Ведь по сути мы в таком случае получим и те позиции, в которых есть и оба варианта option_value_id='49' и option_value_id='50', и те позиции, в которых есть только option_value_id='49'.